# Spring Data Redis Cache Implementation

Tags: postgresql-9.1, spring-data-redis

We are currently working on spring boot project with postgreSQl as database.We want to connect our database to redis for cache implementation.Can anyone please answer how to connect postgreSQL to Redis?